# Generating validation code from JSON schema

Tags: python, python-3.x, jsonschema

Is there an existing python package that can help me generate code from a json schema?

For example if I have a JSON object like

```
{       
    "attribute": "obj.value",      
    "operator":  "greater than",      
    "value" : 235 
}
```

I want to be able to take this JSON and apply it as a rule over different objects to see which ones pass the rule.

So ideally I want to have something like

```
is_valid(obj,schema)
```

where

```
is_valid({"value":300},{"attribute":"value","operator":"greater than","value":235})
```

returns True

Comment: A quick google shows https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/, which does exactly what you want.

Comment: You can also use https://github.com/keleshev/schema to the same goal

Comment: @EPo: that's not a JSON Schema library. It has the same goal, but schemas are defined in Python, not in JSON.

Comment: However, your schema doesn't appear to be following the [JSON schema format for numbers](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html). Don't invent your own schema format, stick to a standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`jsonschema` project](https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/) does exactly that, validate Python datastructures against a valid JSON schema:

```
from jsonschema import validate

validate(obj, schema)
```

This returns `None` when the schema is valid, and raises an exception when it is not. If you *must* have a boolean, use:

```
import jsonschema

def is_valid(obj, schema):
    try:
        jsonschema.validate(obj, schema)
    except jsonschema.ValidationError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

You do need to use valid JSON schema constraints. For integer values, [limit the range](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html#range) if your value needs to adhere to boundaries, for example.

The dictionary `{"value": 300}` is a JSON object with a single key, where that single key is an integer with a lower boundary, so define that as a JSON schema:

```
schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "value": {
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 235,
            "exclusiveMinimum": True
        }
    }
}
```

This schema validates your sample value:

```
>>> import jsonschema
>>> def is_valid(obj, schema):
...     try:
...         jsonschema.validate(obj, schema)
...     except jsonschema.ValidationError:
...         return False
...     else:
...         return True
...
>>> schema = {
...     "type": "object",
...     "properties": {
...         "value": {
...             "type": "integer",
...             "minimum": 235,
...             "exclusiveMinimum": True
...         }
...     }
... }
>>> is_valid({'value': 300}, schema)
True
>>> is_valid({'value': 1}, schema)
False
```

Read [*Understanding JSON Schema*](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/index.html) for a great tutorial on how to write such schemas.

Comment: from what I understand jsonschema is only looking at types whereas I am looking at something more complicated like

{"attribute":"value","operator":"not in","value":['a','b','c']}

Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Akshay: if your schema is a valid JSON schema, then `jsonschema.validate()` works. The documentation includes examples like using `"items" : {"enum" : [1, 2, 3]},` to restrict values, for example.

Comment: @Akshay: I added a sample schema for your sample object.

Comment: @Akshay: for your specific example of excluding a subset (not in a given list), you can use `"not": {"enum": ["a", "b", "c"]}`, so JSON schema almost certainly covers your use cases already.